# binary search between two user defined points, returning all names inbetween those two entered

Tags: java

In java, I have to do a binary search, asking the user to select two names that exist in my list and then print all the people between those two, starting at the first name they enter and ending at the second name they enter.  I start by calling the method searchTwoPeople. It's returning nothing.... Here's my code:

```
         public int binarySearch(String searchItem)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = nMembers - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    boolean found = false;

    while (first <= last && !found)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if (bookMembers[mid].lastName.compareTo(searchItem) == 0)
            found = true;
        else if (bookMembers[mid].lastName.compareTo(searchItem) > 0)
            last = mid - 1;
        else
            first = mid + 1;
    }

    if (!found)
        mid = -1; //it is an unsuccessful search

    return mid;
}//end binarySearch


public int findFirstPosition(int position)  
{
    int newPosition = position;

    if (position == 0)  
    {
        return position;
    }
    while (true)  
    {
        if (bookMembers[newPosition-1].lastName.compareTo(bookMembers
          [position].lastName) != 0)
        {
            return newPosition;
        }
        else
        {
            --newPosition;

            if (newPosition == 0)
            {
                return newPosition;  // no more people in list
            }

        }
      // end sequential search
    }
}


    public void searchTwoPeople()  
    {
        String lastName = new String();
        String lastName2 = new String();
        int position, nextPosition;

        int tryCount = 0;
        boolean more = true;

            do
            {
                lastName = inputFirstLastName();//this is the      
         method where I have user input a name where to start search and it's passed in here
                lastName2 = inputSecondLastName(); //user puts 
        name where to end search

                position = binarySearch(lastName);


                if (position == -1)
                {

                    System.out.println ("\n You have no 
      contacts with the name  " + lastName);
                    ++ tryCount;
                }
            }
            while (position == -1 && tryCount < 3);// only let them try 
      3 times....

            if (tryCount == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Only allowed 3 attempts - 
         select a new menu option");
                return;
            }

            nextPosition = findFirstPosition(position);
            while (more)
            {

                    System.out.println(bookMembers
    [nextPosition].toString());

                }

                ++ nextPosition;  // check next person

                if (nextPosition == nMembers) // last person in 
     the list
                {
                    more = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bookMembers
    [nextPosition].lastName.compareTo(lastName2) == 0) 
                    {
                        more = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you? If you don't have a debugger handy, I'm assuming you've added some prints to see which part of your code are being exercised? What do your prints tell you?

Comment: is your sorting working properly ?....and use any debugger , it wont take more than 5 minutes to fix this issue with debugger

Comment: I would encourage you to use for loops where appropriate.  Also, I don't see you checking anywhere to make sure that the second name actually exists in your list.  Not sure if this is intentional but it goes against the description you provided.

Comment: the program shows no errors or suggestions